# Как на чистом JS распарсить массив с JSON

Tags: javascript, json, парсер

На стороне сервера формирую массив вида:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Алексей"},{"id":3,"name":"Валерий"}]
```

Как его распарсить. Приходит только такая строка от сервера.
Либо как вариант могу сформировать строку вида:

```
{"1":{"name":"Алексей"},"3":{"name":"Валерий"}}
```

Но распарсить такую по мне еще сложнее.

Comment: задача передать список пользователей, с БД, бэк на java. Вот и думаю в каком виде лучше передавать и как лучше парсить

Comment: 1. https://learn.javascript.ru/json#метод-json-parse 2. https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch#использование

Comment: а зачем парсить? на сервере ставите хедер `content-type: application/json` и вам придет готовый объект/массив

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно, какой формат Вы хотите получить. Вот пример простейшей логики:

```
var servResp = resp; // [{"id":1,"name":"Алексей"},{"id":3,"name":"Валерий"}]
var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < servResp.length; i++) {
    result[servResp[i].id] = servResp[i].name;
}
```

На выходе получите объект, вида:

```
result = {
  '1': 'Алексей',
  '3': 'Валерий'
}
```

Соответственно, можно будет обращаться по ключам, чтобы получить имя:

```
result[1] -> Алексей
```

Если в качестве ключа необходимо имя - поменяйте поля id и name в цикле выше.

P.S. Если задача Вашего приложения обрабатывать коллекции, то вполне ожидаемо, что вы будете получать массив объектов в качестве ответа.

Comment: задача передать список пользователей, с БД, бэк на java. Вот и думаю в каком виде лучше передавать и как лучше парсить.

Comment: @Алексей Добавьте, пожалуйста, эту информацию в оригинальный вопрос - это же проясняет, что Вы, собственно, хотите сделать

Answer (score 0):

> Как на чистом JS распарсить массив с JSON?

```js
const json = '[{"id":1,"name":"Алексей"},{"id":3,"name":"Валерий"}]';
const parsed = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(parsed);
```

> Приходит только такая строка от сервера

```js
fetch('//httpbin.org/get?something')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(parsed => console.log(parsed))
```

То же, c async/await:

```js
async function getServerData() {
  const res = await fetch('//httpbin.org/get?something');
  const parsed = await res.json();
  
  return parsed;
}

getServerData()
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```